# MacBook Pro mid-2010- water damaged - but it still plays the chime?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, displayport, damage

Hey guys it's been a week since my MacBook Pro had water leaked into it, I'm pretty sure something is wrong :(

But now when I try to boot it up I hear the startup chime, what does this mean?
Should I buy an Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable or give up and just try to back up stuff from the hard drive??
[http://www.amazon.com/Mini_Dis-HDMI-CB6-Mini-DisplayPort-Adapter-Cable/dp/B003OC6LWM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OC6LWM)
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your screen backlight might need replacement. After you turn it on, try pointing a flashlight towards the center of the screen. If you're computer is working fine, you'll see the login screen without any backlight (you'll barely see it).

Comment: I actually forgot I posted this question! I'll take a look at it when I go home.
*Does this mean that the motherboard works?*

Answer (score 0):

1. if you spilled liquid in it, and didn't bother to dry it out prior and stop the corrosion prior to booting it again, it's only going to get worse.  it's not rocket science--water damages electronics, so waving fairy dust or doing a hail mary isn't going to somehow prevent it.
2. you have to get it cleaned out AND stop the corrosion. if you don't know what you're doing on that, by ALL means find someone who does.
3. if the display is dim, there's damage. if it's a 2009 or later, it's likely worth repairing. but you need to find a company that does this.  Not your local 'geek-squad' (they only throw parts at issues, not actually repair things)..

There are a few US shops:  techrestore.com (i dunno if they're still in business), wegenermedia.com (my personal favorite), and powerbookmedic.com, (who i've had some frustrating dealings with)... these people will actually be able to figure out the issue and get it fixed, rather than just throw parts (and $$) at the problem...